# not getting desired value from PHP into JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay so I am currently working on an up- and downvotesystem on a forumwebsite on which users can hit the upvote button on which the number will update without the page reloading. I already have working code for the TABLE containing the up- and downvotes. I also have an AJAX request in whcich the page doesnt reload upon hitting the button.

the code I have used for this:

```
            function update_upvotes(thread_id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../includes/update_upvotes.inc.php",
                    data: {
                        thread_id: thread_id
                    },
                success: function(data){
               console.log('worky');
               alert("upvotes currently: "+data); // not worky, derpy
            }
                });

            var upvote = document.getElementById(thread_id);
            alert(upvote.innerHTML);
            var x = <?php echo $num_upvotes; ?>;
            alert(x);
            }
```

PHP:

```
<?php

  include_once '../includes/dbh_discussion.inc.php';
  $conn = db_discussion_connect();
  $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(upvoted) AS num_upvotes FROM upvote WHERE thread_id = :tid AND upvoted = 1");
  $sql->bindParam(':tid', $thread_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sql->execute();
  $rowup = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $num_upvotes = $rowup['num_upvotes'];
  echo $num_upvotes;
```

$thread_id is a variable declared by the following code

```
    include_once '../includes/dbh_discussion.inc.php';
    session_start();

    $conn = db_discussion_connect();
    $number_threads = 5;
    $page_id = intval(htmlspecialchars($_GET['page']));
    $start = $page_id * $number_threads - $number_threads;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM threads LIMIT :start, {$number_threads}";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':start', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    ?>


while($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $thread_id = $result['thread_id'];
```

The problem is that after the intial request upon loading the page, $num_upvotes will get a value of 0 for every request thereafter which is not in accordance with our database values. Any ideas on what is the issue  here??

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: added definition of $thread_id, within the while loop there is echoed HTML code in which there are button which carry values which are on its turn passed to the PHP file via the post method

Comment: I don't see the definition for `$thread_id`. You should include it in your example, as it seems quite important.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks, added it!

Comment: You don't seem to be sending `page` as a GET parameter in your javascript code. Where does it come from? And why are you ignoring the perfectly good `thread_id` you are actually sending with your ajax request?

Comment: $_GET['page'] is merely intended to show threads in interval [n,m] and is not needed in the js code. Gonna change the thread_id thingy in a sec, and update asap

Comment: still returning 0 :( 'worky' is logged by the console... The alerts display as follows:    1. returns 2, 2. returns upvotes currently: 0, 3. returns 0

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving `thread_id`? I mean, do you see it both in the brower's developer tools network tab *and* in the php if you put an `error_log` at the beginning? Anyway, you should put some debugging `error_log` around your php to check for various things as they happen and try to understand where the error is.

Comment: Hmmm embarassing but... I forgot $_POST['thread_id'] in my PHP code :) issue is still not resolved though, but i kindly thank you for investing time in my stupidity so far

Comment: And got it working, had to add a bitwise AND in the onsubmit function in the button so that both functions would be evaluated!